# Deployment error: "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid"

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

**What happens?**

I publish a website to UnoEuro on a windows server.

When I do I keep getting the error message:

> "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

**What have I set up/tried?**

What I've done is that I've created a .NET Core 2.1 Web API which hosts fine locally on my computer using IIS. I have then published the web api to the hosting site UnoEuro where I can see that the files are uploaded as they should be.

I asked the hosting sites support, they told me to just ensure that it was deployed as self-contained but that otherwise they could not help further. It looks like there is a hosting issue of some sort related to that it cannot seem to find the webconfig file. At least that's what the error message says.

Is there any form of setup I should make? A configuration I should change? Should I set up some SSL settings in the web API which I might have missed? When I started the project I told it to enforce HTTPS, but surely I should get another error message if that was the fault?

I've tried publishing with the target runtime set to both x64 and x86.

I've never published an API like this to anything but Azure before, so I might be doing a thing or two wrong but I cannot see what it should be? I have Googled around but not found anything that seems relevant which has worked.

Most of the solutions seem related to changing the server environment which I don't have so much control over, I mostly just have control over the application/web api, at least that's what it looks like to me.

Hope you have any suggestions, I'm all eyes n ears.

Side question: Should I use IIS Manager for this? I'm currently publishing through Visual Studio 2017.

**Images for further understanding**

*Publishing settings*

[image: Publish info]

*Deployed/published files*

[image: Deployedfiles]

*Error message I get*

[image: Error message]

EDIT:

I tried moving the files to /public_html on the same domain as ISS Manager seemed to indicate it expected the config file to be there.

That then resulted in a different error message as you see below.

Link from error message: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

[image: new error message]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly, but I think the issue is that the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle is not installed on the server. There's two pieces to hosting in IIS. First, you need the .NET Core runtime, and then you need the ASP.NET Core hosting module for IIS. Deploying as self-contained buys you the runtime, but not the hosting module in IIS. There's non-standard sections in the Web.config created by publishing an ASP.NET Core app. The hosting module shims in support in IIS for these config sections (among other things). Therefore, the config error seems to imply that this is not happening.

If you don't control the server, there's not much you can do about it. Honestly, at this point, I wouldn't host anywhere where you do not at least have some measure of control over the environment. You can get a full VPS from numerous hosting services for $5 or less a month. Either continue hosting in Azure, or look into other respected cloud providers like DigitalOcean, AWS, etc.

Comment: The webhosts FAQ section says they use "RuntimeFrameworkVersion 1.1"

Do you think if I could somehow convince them to get 2.1 running that it would work? I might have more freedom on the webhost than it looks like. I am not so experienced yet so maybe I just dont see it. But it seems like whenever I try to access something through IIS Manager I get denied. Any hints as to what I should at the very minimum have access to in there?

Comment: Well, frankly, that's just another strike against that host. The 1.X branch of ASP.NET Core is frankly crap. It wasn't ready for prime time. I don't suppose it hurts to ask if they can upgrade, but honestly, even if they do, the fact that they left it on 1.1 this long doesn't bode well for future updates. As far as the hosting module goes, that's not something you can do through IIS. It has to be installed on the system by someone with admin privileges. Again, I suppose you can ask, but really at what point do you just move on to a better hosting provider?

Comment: I mainly used them as they were beginner friendly and cheap, plus I didn't consider that it might be a problem to host it as they advertised .NET Core as part of their hosting capability. I think i'll pop them a message and ask since in general I like their service. But I can understand your reason for asking.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but the runtime ought to be 2.1 for it to work. Would the hosting bundle need the same version (2.1)?

Comment: I'm not actually sure on that one. I *think* it's version-independent. Like, you don't have to install the bundle again when there's a new runtime update. However, that doesn't preclude some new version of ASP.NET Core needing a change in the hosting module.

Comment: If it's version independent and they supported 1.1 it would make sense for me if the self-contained version should be able to run. As the self-contained part then as I understood contains the runtime. But yea it might need a change. I'll see what they reply and otherwise consider other options.

Comment: It's worth noting that they only specify support for ".NET Core", not necessarily *ASP.NET Core*. That might just be technical misuse of terminology, but it is possible to run ASP.NET Core entirely self-hosted under Kestrel or to use something other than IIS as a reverse proxy. In other words, they can still claim .NET Core support and not necessarily support running an ASP.NET Core webapp using IIS as a reverse proxy (which is the only scenario that requires the hosting bundle to be install). It would be *weird*, but possible.

Comment: Installing the .NET Core Hosting Installer Bundle on the server for IIS solved the issue I was having (the exact same error message as the original poster).  This was for ASP.NET Core 5 Web API, even trying to run it as a self-contained package.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Net Core Hosting Boundle is missing.

The ASP.NET Core Runtime enables you to run existing web/server applications. On Windows, we recommend installing the Hosting Bundle, which includes the .NET Runtime and IIS support.

You can download here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet